# export map shapes from photoshop to excel

Tags: excel, photoshop, shapes

I want to create map shapes in Excel to analysing Sales and Stocks in our restaurants in NYC.

I can create own shape in Photoshop, but i don't know how to export own shapes **from Photoshop to Excel**.
Do you have any idea how to create map shapes in excel (ex: map of nyc by adm. district)?

Answer (score 0):

From Photoshop you can save a file in **.jpeg** format.  This can easily be imported into Excel, reshaped, and positioned as you desire.